# разное поведение разметки для разных версий

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk, material-design

К вопросам о поведении разметки в `android` - если в версиях после `lolipop` все работает как нужно, а до `lolipop` разметка становится корявой, как это исправить?

Конкретно - есть список `recyclerView`, в нем `items`, так вот в версии после 5 все выглядит, как нужно.

Если запускаю в версиях ниже (пробовал на 4.1.1 и 4.2), то индикатор, показывающий количество лайков съезжает влево.

Разметка одна и та же, как такие баги исправляются вообще?Писать каким-то образом отдельно под версии ниже 5-ой, я не понимаю.

Comment: Покажите, что ли, разметку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под такие случаи пишут `layout.xml` с таким же названием только для версии API выше т.е. написав `layout.xml` с корректным видом для более нового API, кладем его в папку с названием `layout-v19`,  все что выше 19 версии включительно будет отображаться как сказано в этом `layout`

Comment: решение правильное, только наоборот - такая разметка будет применена на API19 и **выше**. Смотрите [офф.руководство](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), в частности Таблица2, строка Уровни платформы (в самом конце таблицы)

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за комментарий, поправил.

Comment: не совсем правильно. Нужно не называть файл `layout-v19.xml`, а положить файл с разметкой для 19+ API в папку `layout-v19`, а файл должен называться так же само - `layout.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Стоит изучить тему [Предоставление альтернативных ресурсов](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), если проблемы связаны с объективными причинами, вроде иного парсинга одинаковых атрибутов на более новых API или иные параметры в теме, например вид и размер виджетов. В вашем случае альтернативный ресурс будет по версии API.

Так же существует вероятность, что в разметке используются атрибуты, которые не поддерживаются в более старых API (вроде `android:layout_marginStart` поддерживается с API17). Такие атрибуты игнорируются при парсинге разметки на более старых API и своих функций, естественно, не выполняют.